# Data mismatch in Solr indexing and searching

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Im running a full import on Solr pointing to an Oracle DB, I get this message when done with indexing, but when I run a select query with

```
q=*:*
```

I get only 4000 records as numfound, Please let me know where I'm missing and why this mismatch.

```
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">99999</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2014-03-07 11:07:22</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 99999 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2014-03-07 11:08:29</str>
<str name="Optimized">2014-03-07 11:08:29</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">99999</str>
<str name="Time taken ">0:1:7.133</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: In your solrconfig.xml check if you have any query restrictions under this element: `<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">` or if you are using a custom req handler, check that one.

Comment: Dou you still see the same result even you send an explicit commit via Curl?